# display time per minute using start and end date time

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, ksh

I want to write a script that will display the time per minute between two date and time. The Start and End time gap can be anything, could be 5minutes, 3hours, 30days, etc.

Example:

```
Start time: 2019-12-31 23:57:00
End Time  : 2020-01-01 00:03:00
```

Result:

```
 2019-12-31 23:57:00
 2019-12-31 23:58:00
 2019-12-31 23:59:00
 2020-01-01 00:00:00
 2020-01-01 00:01:00
 2020-01-01 00:02:00
 2020-01-01 00:03:00
```

Edit:
Im getting the error below when using the `-d` option.

```
     date: Not a recognized flag: d
     Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `date` that can handle expressions like `+1 minute`, it's pretty easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
start='2019-12-31 23:57:00'
end='2020-01-01 00:03:00'

date=$start
while [[ $date < $end || $date == $end ]] ; do
    echo "$date"
    date=$(date -d "+1 minute $date" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
done
```